# Can't navigate to other pages in Angular 5 application, after the deploying project (ng build)

Tags: angular, deployment, build, routes, production

When I'm testing my Angular application (v5) with the following command:

`ng serve --open`

I can navigate to the any registered route of my application. When I want to serve my application after the building process via:

`ng build` or `ng build --prod`

I'm getting the 404 error, after navigating to any route. If to read the [official tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/deployment), there shouldn't be any complex actions with the project deployment.

I have made a search and found the proposal to add the `--base-href=/` option in build command, but also NO success.

I'm using the next HTTP-server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

**Possible question to me:**

**Q1:** How do you serve the Angular app?

**A1:** Using the `http-server --cors` command of the NPM-package at the application directory, so the `--base-href` is referencing correctly

**Q2:** What is your routing configuration (source code)?

**A2:** My routes are very simple, because I'm learning the Angular v5 tutorials, so don't expect something special, the source code is next:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SalesComponent }       from './sales/sales.component';
import { ConsumersComponent }   from './consumers/consumers.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'consumers' , component: ConsumersComponent },
    { path: 'sales', component: SalesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**AppRoutingModule** is provided in the **app.modude.ts** file (`imports:` in **@NgModule**).

**Q3:** Does your Angular app depend on backend (server-side app)?

**A3:** It doesn't. It has only the mock objects for data simulating. They are defined as static data in the separated class. I didn't go so far from the Angular tutorial at official website. Just wanted to serve the `ng build --prod` version with my favorite tiny HTTP-server.

So, I can navigate to other pages, when using the `ng serve` command, but I can't do the same, after building the project. Tutorials provide the description, that I can just serve the built files as the static ones with any HTTP-server, but no success for me.

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, due the [official deployment guide](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml).

You should configure your HTTP-server to follow the **Front Controller Pattern**. I have tested it with the nginx server, using the next configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;        
    }
}
```

And all is working pretty fine now.

You can do the same with the `.htaccess` file, if you're using the Apache server or with the `web.config` file, if the IIS is your HTTP-server and so on.